# Spring autowired annotation with java timertask

Tags: spring

Autowired annotation doesn't work. I thought there must be a problem with Timertask or run method. My other classes working fine(I mean Autowired annotation initialize genericService without any problem) but in this class genericService value is null. Is there any idea?

```
public class UsersUpdateTask extends TimerTask {
    @Autowired
    GenericService genericService;

  @Override
  public void run() {
     //genericService.save() gives null pointer.
  }

}
```

My applicationContext definition;

```
<bean id="usersUpdateTask" class="myPackage.UsersUpdateTask">               
</bean>

<bean id="genericLogger" class="utilPack.Logger">                
</bean> 

<bean id="genericService" class="servicePack.GenericService">
```

This class working perfectly;

```
public class Logger implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private GenericService genericService; //works fine
.....
}
```

There is a method in another class to call UsersUpdateTask's run method;

```
public void updateUsersList(){        
    timer.schedule(new UsersUpdateTask(), 1000, 60*60*1000);
}
```

Comment: First check if `annotation-config` is turned on.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes it is turned on. I got some other beans working perfectly.

Comment: Where is the `GenericService` bean declared?

Comment: Last question and then I'm stumped: how are you using the `usersUpdateTask` bean?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I updated my answer. Is it about how I initialize UsersUpdateTask class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well there it is

```
timer.schedule(new UsersUpdateTask(), 1000, 60*60*1000);
```

you're creating the object yourself. Spring can't autowire objects it doesn't control or process. Use the injected `UsersUpdateTask` bean.

Comment: @hellzone It's not obvious at first. If you're expecting to use a Spring bean, makes sure it comes from Spring :).

Comment: This is like a sentence from a holy book "you're creating the object yourself. Spring can't autowire objects it doesn't control or process." . So divine that it helps solve many errors